# Is there a way to restart a callback mid function in Dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Wondering if there is any way to have one of my Dash update callbacks start over if certain criteria are met within the function. Maybe it is some sort of exception I can raise, similar to dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate?

Example:

```
@app.callback(Output(...),[Input(...)])
def update_fxn(....):
   if x:
      return [a, b, c]
   if y:
      #restart this callback somehow
```

Let me know if you guys have any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the criteria? What affects it? Could you provide an example?